# BootstrapValidator

Tags: bootstrap, валидация

Подскажите как решить данную проблему.Есть datepicker на него надо повесисть валидацию,после нажатия кнопки Submit все как надо валидируется,показывает что не выбрана дата,но после того как выбираю валидация не проходит не при каких обстоятельствах,что только не пробовал уже.

```
    <label for="select_date" class=" hx2_">WHAT IS YOUR ANNIVERSARY DATE OR DO YOU HAVE START DATE?</label>
       <div class=" input-group date">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
       <input id="select_date" data-type="commission" name="date" type='text' class="datepicker form-control" data-provide="datepicker" placeholder="-- Select date --"/>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                                    <button type="submit" data-href="#tab_2" class="btn_ bg_green btn_tab_next">NEXT<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i></button>
                                </div> 


$('#create_commission').bootstrapValidator({

            fields: {
                date: {
                    message: "This field is required",
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: "This field is required"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }});
```

Пробовал и по onChange datepicker заново инициализировать валидатор,всеравно ничего не помогает!

Comment: Возможно требуется data-value для валидации

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в этом все дело.Валидация же срабатывает и без него!

Comment: Одно другому не мешает.